# Connection with webservice in Xamarin android login fail

Tags: c#, android, mongodb, xamarin

Lately I’ve been experimenting with Xamarin trying to build an android app. I’ve also set up a database (MongoDB) with a node webservice. The user data will be stored in there.

Now, I've a login page and was trying to make a connection with the webservice. The connections do work but when I want to test my login page it always says wrong password/user. Whether I type something in or not it always says the same.

> Response: {"message": "Wrong password.", "success": false}

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    EditText txtMail, txtPwd;
    Button buttonSignIn;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        txtMail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTxtMail);
        txtPwd = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTxtPwd);
        buttonSignIn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_SignIn);

        buttonSignIn.Click += async (sender, e) => {
            string url = "localhost:3000/login";

            JsonValue json = await FetchLoginAsync (url);
        };
    }

    private async Task<JsonValue> FetchLoginAsync (string url)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        /*
        string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMail + ":" + txtPwd));
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);*/

        request.Method = "POST"; 
        request.Headers.Add("email", txtMail.Text);
        request.Headers.Add("password", txtPwd.Text);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse Httpresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
            {
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run (() => JsonObject.Load (stream));
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString ());

                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I also tried the piece of code I put in comment. But that also not works (and I believe that's not the right way to do it).

I’m new to this, maybe it’s something obvious that I did wrong or totally misunderstood something. Can someone please help me out of this? I’ve been stuck for 2 days already.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Use the IP of your server, not localhost.  "localhost" will loopback to the simulator/device you are using, not the PC it is running on.

Comment: Yeps, tried it already. But still got the same results :(

Comment: Is the failure message is coming from your server, you should debug there to see why it is failing.

Comment: Ah I see, `request.Header.Add()` won't work because on the server side it was said to send it with the body and not with the header. 
Do you have any sugestions how I can pass the credentials with the body?

Comment: I would try using a tool like Postman to verify what exactly the request should look like first.  Assuming they just want the credentials sent as json in the body, there are lots of posts on SO and elsewhere about sending data via POST using HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 1):

you can post parameters through body like this:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.TokenUrl) })
            {
                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", Settings.RefreshToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Settings.ClientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Settings.ClientSecret)
                }); 

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, formContent);
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var json = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);

                    Settings.RefreshToken = json["refresh_token"].ToString();
                    Settings.AccessToken = json["access_token"].ToString();

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem like this:

```
buttonSignIn.Click += delegate {

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( LOCALHOST + "login");                
            var postData = "email=" + txtMail.Text;
            postData += "&password=" + txtPwd.Text;

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);                
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;                
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }                
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();               
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```